# Can I disable the warning when a group policy restricts program execution?

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy

I'm running Windows XP SP3 Pro and I've set up a GPO that prevents the execution of a file. It works fine, but when I try to execute that file I get a warning dialog:

> This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer.

I tried to do the same by creating a security policy, however that also produces a warning dialog.

My question: Is it possible to prevent file execution without such visual feedback (I don't mind entries in the event log)?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for this?  Generally, I kind of like users to be told by the computer when something they're doing is against security policy - it might just put a little fear in them to prevent them from trying something like that again.

Comment: @Iszi A lot of programs will run without the user deliberately trying to run them.

Comment: @trlkly Fair point. But on a managed system, you should have users see this also. It means either that something legitimate didn't make it into the whitelist, and so some functionality is probably broken that shouldn't be, or some unauthorized software has been installed and sysadmins need to be quickly notified. Event log review/alerting is great, but a user who's gotten a scary-looking notification is usually going to draw attention & action faster. You want that in the case of a possible security incident.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you are looking for : I believe that the restrictions message is hard-coded and I don't know of a way to disable it.

The only help I can think of is to use a utility that will get rid of this error-window as soon as it appears.

Here are some such free utilities (that I have never used) :

[ClickOff](http://www.johanneshuebner.com/en/clickoff.shtml)
[Window Clicker](http://www.murgee.com/window-clicker/)
[NagBlast](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Popup-Ad-Spyware-Blockers/NagBlast.shtml)

If for some reason none of them is right for you, you can always roll your own by using
a macro recording tool such as [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: I had a similar problem. ClickOff worked a charm!